# C# FTP upload stuck on particular file

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have problem with my C# program. I have an big zip archive (about 4Gb) which is split in small pieces, in fact each piece is 100 Mb. So, when my program start to upload files it working perfectly until 14th piece is starting uploaded. my program upload only ~90 Mb of that piece and then I receive error "The remote server returned an error: (451) Local error in processing". My C# program detect if file was not uploaded successfully and trying to upload it, so I got a never ending loop.

```
private static void SendToFtp(AppConfig cfg, string zipName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting FTP upload");
    NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(cfg.FtpUserName, cfg.FtpPassword);
   try
   {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(cfg.ZipFolder);
    byte[] buffer = null;
    foreach (var file in di.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        using (Stream st = File.OpenRead(file.FullName))
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(st))
        {

            bool success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);

                sb.Append($"ftp://{cfg.FtpHost}/{file.Name}");
                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.UseBinary = false;
                request.UsePassive = false;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1000;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(cfg.FtpUserName, cfg.FtpPassword);

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        requestStream.Flush();
                        requestStream.Close();

                        var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        success = !success;
                        Console.WriteLine($"======================{file.Name}=======================");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message:{resp.StatusDescription}");
                        Console.WriteLine($" Status code: {resp.StatusCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"========================================================");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        request.Abort();
                        Console.WriteLine($"MSG: {ex.Message}");

                    }
                }
                sb.Clear();
            }
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("FTP upload finished");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}; {ex.Source}");
    }

}
```

So, can someone help me or point me where I'm wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: A 451 response code may be sent in response to any command initiating a file transfer. It is a transient negative response, which means the error condition is a temporary one. It is usually sent in response to the server encountering an unexpected local error when processing data it is transferring or receiving.

Comment: I've got this error only from one machine running under Windows Server 2012 R2, from my PC, where this program is developed, there is no problem

Comment: on error like that, you could just disconnect and reconnect and continue sending.  Sometimes there are limits to times.